# Calculating the latus rectum of an ellipse in Python

Tags: python, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the length of the semilatus rectum (L) through a foci of an ellipse (e.g. the blue line in this diagram taken from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemilatusRectum.html)

[image: Semilatus Rectum]

Where

L = a(1 - e**2) (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemilatusRectum.html)

and

e = c / a (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eccentricity.html)

I have written up this code in python to calculate L but am not getting the desired result.

My code is:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 10 # semimajor axis
b = 5 # semiminor axis

# calculate and plot semilatus rectum
for c in range(0, a):
    eccentricity = c / a
    L = (a-c) * (1. - eccentricity**2)
    plt.plot([0, L], [c, c])

# plot ellipse
for t in range(0, 360):
    x = a*math.cos(t)
    y = b*math.sin(t)
    plt.scatter(b*math.cos(t), a*math.sin(t), s=1, c="r", edgecolor="none")
```

And the result is:

[image: Semilatus Rectum result]

####### UPDATE

Thanks to @slatertyranus I have realised the error in my question

Comment: Wait, why are you plotting things? Are you trying to calculate a number, or make a plot?

Comment: I am plotting them to display I have the right (or wrong!) length where c is the foci location.

Comment: The latus rectum is defined at a right angle to that, and there's only one actual focus location, so you can't just use a number of different values for `c` and expect it to work.

Comment: Thanks @SlaterTyranus I see my error, I will go back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

You're question has me a little baffled, but here's how you would calculate the latus rectum of an ellipse:

```
import math

def latum_rectum(semi_minor, semi_major):
    focus_distance = math.sqrt(semi_major**2 - semi_minor**2)
    eccentricity = focus_distance/semi_major
    return 2*semi_major(1 - eccentricity**2)
```

I hope that helps. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do with the plot, so let me know if you have any more questions.